# How to add termux icon in my Bluestack home pages

Tags: emulator, bluestacks

I had install Bluestack in my windows 10.But unfortunately the Termux icon is not in my bluestack homepages.Therefor I sincerely need help from you all that help me to solve this problem.

I had install termux in my bluestack and it run without any error but it doesn't appear in my home pages.

May anyone know how to make it on my homepages?